# Symfony 5 and GDPR: managing cookies

Tags: symfony, cookies, google-tag-manager, gdprconsentform

I'm on Symfony 5. I'm trying to find a GDPR compliant solution to manage cookies.

I tried several solutions like Axeptio and Cookiebot, but their free version has limitations: only 2 cookies (eg GA4 and Facebook pixel) for the first and only 100 pages for the second.

Have you tried symfony bundles? Have you tried coding yourself using Google Tag Manager? Can you share your experience to help me find a solution?

Thanks :).

Comment: This is more frontend thing, not Symfony. It depends what you need. If you want to store consents in some DB etc. It's usually not like: here is the complete solution, just install it. You should understand what's needed at first. In general, GDPR and cookies are not the same thing! And yes, if you want to use some "full" solution, you have to pay. Otherwise you have to do it manually and it brings things like categorizing cookies (analytics, marketing, necessary, ..) and do some other things to follow rules. We use https://github.com/orestbida/cookieconsent/

Comment: @Kamil, Thank you for your answer. The solution you are using looks good. But I started using tarteaucitron which suits me well too. https://github.com/AmauriC/tarteaucitron.js/